# Java 8 Stream API - Selecting only values after Collectors.groupingBy(..)

Tags: java, grouping, java-stream

Say I have the following collection of `Student` objects which consist of Name(String), Age(int) and City(String).

I am trying to use Java's Stream API to achieve the following sql-like behavior:

```
SELECT MAX(age)
FROM Students
GROUP BY city
```

Now, I found two different ways to do so:

```
final List<Integer> variation1 =
            students.stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getCity, Collectors.maxBy((s1, s2) -> s1.getAge() - s2.getAge())))
                    .values()
                    .stream()
                    .filter(Optional::isPresent)
                    .map(Optional::get)
                    .map(Student::getAge)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And the other one:

```
final Collection<Integer> variation2 =
            students.stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getCity,
                            Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.maxBy((s1, s2) -> s1.getAge() - s2.getAge()),
                                    optional -> optional.get().getAge())))
                    .values();
```

In both ways, one has to `.values() ...` and filter the empty groups returned from the collector.

Is there any other way to achieve this required behavior?

These methods remind me of `over partition by` sql statements...

Thanks

---

**Edit:** All the answers below were really interesting, but unfortunately this is not what I was looking for, since what I try to get is just the values. I don't need the keys, just the values.

Comment: What do you mean by "filter the empty groups"?

Comment: I mean not have to call `values()` since I don't need the keys at all

Comment: The implementation _must_ use the keys to figure out how to group the elements.  You can discard the keys afterwards, but that doesn't mean you don't need them in the meantime.

Answer (score 31):

Do not always stick with `groupingBy`. Sometimes `toMap` is the thing you need:

```
Collection<Integer> result = students.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Student::getCity, Student::getAge, Integer::max))
    .values();
```

Here you just create a `Map` where keys are cities and values are ages. In case when several students have the same city, merge function is used which just selects maximal age here. It's faster and cleaner.

Comment: I added a `groupingBy` based solution that is *almost* as simple, but as long as the OP is interested in the ages only, the `toMap` solution clearly is the simplest.

Answer (score 16):

As addition to [Tagir’s great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35715206/2711488) using `toMap` instead of `groupingBy`, here the short solution, if you want to stick to `groupingBy`:

```
Collection<Integer> result = students.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getCity,
                 Collectors.reducing(-1, Student::getAge, Integer::max)))
    .values();
```

Note that this three arg `reducing` collector already performs a mapping operation, so we don’t need to nest it with a `mapping` collector, further, providing an identity value avoids dealing with `Optional`. Since ages are always positive, providing `-1` is sufficient and since a group will always have at least one element, the identity value will never show up as a result.

Still, I think Tagir’s `toMap` based solution is preferable in this scenario.

---

The `groupingBy` based solution becomes more interesting when you want to get the actual students having the maximum age, e.g

```
Collection<Student> result = students.stream().collect(
   Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getCity, Collectors.reducing(null, BinaryOperator.maxBy(
     Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.comparingInt(Student::getAge)))))
).values();
```

well, actually, even this can also be expressed using the `toMap` collector:

```
Collection<Student> result = students.stream().collect(
    Collectors.toMap(Student::getCity, Function.identity(),
        BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparingInt(Student::getAge)))
).values();
```

You can express almost everything with both collectors, but `groupingBy` has the advantage on its side when you want to perform a [mutable reduction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#MutableReduction) on the values.

Comment: I just realized that even getting the actual student can be done easily using `toMap`, so it requires more complex scenarios to get a benefit from `groupingBy` here…

Comment: Nevertheless the approach is interesting. I never combined `groupingBy` with two-arg/three-arg `reduce`. Probably it's useful sometimes...

Comment: @Tagir Valeev: that’s why I added it despite your answer being better for this particular use case.

Comment: @Holger Isn't `Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparingInt(Student::getAge)), Optional::get)` more straight-forward though?  (For the second example.)

Comment: @antak: well, in this case, using `toMap` is more straight-forward, even for the second example. `collectingAndThen(…, Optional::get)` might be cleaner than `Collectors.reducing(null, …)`, but it also implies that the collector has to go through the entire map to apply the finisher function at the end, so I sometimes prefer the downstream collector that produces the intended result in the first place. But as said, using `toMap` is even simpler here.

Comment: @Holger oic wrt the extra finisher pass.  By `toMap` do you mean using something like `(a, b) -> a.getAge() >= b.getAge() ? a : b` for the merger?  Or is there some way to prevent that doubling up of `getAge()`?

Comment: @antak: you can use `BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparingInt(Student::g‌​etAge))` as merge function.

Comment: @Holger: That's brilliant!  Should put that conclusion to your *solution becomes more interesting when you want to get the actual students* remark.  Because I landed here after Googling for that use case.

Comment: @antak: I inserted it.

Answer (score 2):

The second approach calls `get()` on an `Optional`; this is usually a bad idea as you don't know if the optional will be empty or not (use `orElse()`, `orElseGet()`, `orElseThrow()` methods instead). While you might argue that in this case there always be a value since you generate the values from the student list itself, this is something to keep in mind.

Based on that, you might turn the variation 2 into:

```
final Collection<Integer> variation2 =
     students.stream()
             .collect(collectingAndThen(groupingBy(Student::getCity,
                                                   collectingAndThen(
                                                      mapping(Student::getAge, maxBy(naturalOrder())),
                                                      Optional::get)), 
                                        Map::values));
```

Although it really starts to be difficult to read, I'll probably use the variant 1:

```
final List<Integer> variation1 =
        students.stream()
            .collect(groupingBy(Student::getCity,
                                mapping(Student::getAge, maxBy(naturalOrder()))))
            .values()
            .stream()
            .map(Optional::get)
            .collect(toList());
```

Comment: This is now my preferred answer, though I'd personally move `Map.values()` outside the `collect` (though I'd keep everything else inside).

Comment: Yes, that would improve a bit the readability. As a reference I let it here: `final Collection<Integer> variation2 = students.stream().collect(groupingBy(Student::getCity, collectingAndThen(mapping(Student::getAge, maxBy(naturalOrder())), Optional::get))).values(); `

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is my implementation 

    public class MaxByTest {

        static class Student {

        private int age;
        private int city;        

        public Student(int age, int city) {
            this.age = age;
            this.city = city;
        }

        public int getCity() {
            return city;
        }

        public int getAge() {
            return age;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return " City : " + city + " Age : " + age;
        }



    }

    static List<Student> students = Arrays.asList(new Student[]{
        new Student(10, 1),
        new Student(9, 2),        
        new Student(8, 1),        
        new Student(6, 1),
        new Student(4, 1),
        new Student(8, 2),
        new Student(9, 2),
        new Student(7, 2),        
    });

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Comparator<Student> comparator = (p1, p2) -> Integer.compare( p1.getAge(), p2.getAge());
        final List<Student> studets =
            students.stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getCity, 
                            Collectors.maxBy(comparator))).values().stream().map(Optional::get).collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(studets);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
        List<BeanClass> list1 = new ArrayList<BeanClass>();
        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        list1.add(new BeanClass(123,abc,99.0,formatter.parse("2018-02-01")));
        list1.add(new BeanClass(456,xyz,99.0,formatter.parse("2014-01-01")));
        list1.add(new BeanClass(789,pqr,95.0,formatter.parse("2014-01-01")));
        list1.add(new BeanClass(1011,def,99.0,formatter.parse("2014-01-01")));
        Map<Object, Optional<Double>> byDate = list1.stream()
       .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> formatter.format(p.getCurrentDate()),
        Collectors.mapping(BeanClass::getAge, Collectors.maxBy(Double::compare))));
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided some explanation in addition to your code to help people to understand what it's doing.

Comment: It is always best practice to go through the code example in your answer instead of just pasting the code or putting a link to another resource.