# Remove Duplicate Elements from ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

We have a ArrayList. It contains duplicate employee objects with only difference in their age, but name and id will be same. So while removing the duplicates, we have to keep the employee with maximum age and remove all other duplicates. This is one of the questions asked by an interviewer in one of the interviews.

I tried solving this. It is giving me correct result, but I am not sure with my approach as I am changing the state of the object in equals method. Is there any other approach to solve this problem?
Code Snippet below: -

```
package practice;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

class Employee {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int age;

    Employee(int id, String name, int age) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return (31*(name.hashCode()) + 31);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {        
        if ((obj instanceof Employee)) {
            if (((Employee)obj).getId() == this.id && (((Employee)obj).getName().equalsIgnoreCase(this.name))) {
                if(this.age > ((Employee)obj).getAge()) {
                    ((Employee)obj).setAge(this.age);
                }
                return true;
            } else 
                return false;
        } else 
            return false;
    }
}

public class ListDuplicateRemoval {

    public static List<Employee> removeDuplicates(List<Employee> employees) {
        Set<Employee> set = new HashSet<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < employees.size(); i++) {
            set.add(employees.get(i));
        }        
        /*for (int i = 0; i < set.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(set.iterator().next().getAge());
        }*/
        employees.removeAll(employees);
        employees.addAll(set);
        return employees;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employee e1 = new Employee(1, "Mike", 20);
        Employee e2 = new Employee(1, "Mike", 21);
        List <Employee> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(e1);
        list.add(e2);
        removeDuplicates(list);
        System.out.println(list.size());
        System.out.println(list.get(0).getAge());
    }
}
```

Comment: Stack overflow is not for code review, you'll want to check out: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Edited the question and asking for any alternative approaches.

Comment: did you implement .equals or was that given to you?

Comment: See answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35710619/java-8-stream-api-selecting-only-values-after-collectors-groupingby). It seems that's almost what you need.

Answer (score 1):

No this solution is really awful. equals should never, ever, modify the state of the objects it's comparing.

Create a class containing the information that identifies employees uniquely, and which properly override equal() and hashCode(). Then use a Map containing these identication info as key, and the employee with the largest age as value. Then get the values and make it a list:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class Employee {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int age;

    Employee(int id, String name, int age) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", age=" + age +
            '}';
    }
}

class DuplicateRemoval {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Employee> employeeList = Arrays.asList(
            new Employee(1, "Joe", 23),
            new Employee(2, "Joe", 23),
            new Employee(1, "Joe", 21),
            new Employee(1, "Jane", 22),
            new Employee(1, "Jane", 20)
        );

        Map<EmployeeKey, Employee> map = employeeList.stream().collect(
            Collectors.toMap(e -> new EmployeeKey(e.getId(), e.getName()),
                             Function.identity(),
                             (e1, e2) -> e1.getAge() > e2.getAge() ? e1 : e2)
        );

        List<Employee> result = new ArrayList<>(map.values());
        System.out.println("result = " + result);
    }

    private static class EmployeeKey {
        private int id;
        private String name;

        EmployeeKey(int id, String name) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) {
                return true;
            }
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
                return false;
            }
            EmployeeKey that = (EmployeeKey) o;
            return id == that.id &&
                Objects.equals(name, that.name);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(id, name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not so much proficient in Java 8. Can you send me this part of code in java 7?Map<EmployeeKey, Employee> map = employeeList.stream().collect(
            Collectors.toMap(e -> new EmployeeKey(e.getId(), e.getName()),
                             Function.identity(),
                             (e1, e2) -> e1.getAge() > e2.getAge() ? e1 : e2)
        );

Comment: You should be able to figure that out by yourself, just by reading the explanations of the code I gave, not tomention the javadocs. All it does is putting the employee in the map, using the employee's key as key, unless the map already contains an employee for that key whose age is bigger than the current employee. Doing that in Java 7, with a simple loop, should be very easy.

Answer (score 0):

Implement a `Comparator<Employee>`

1. Have the `compare` method take into account age.
2. Have the `equals` method ignore age.

use `equals` to identify duplicates.

use `compare` to determine which duplicate to keep.